# How to make QSortFilterProxyModel work with custom ItemDelegate of QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

Below is my code change to implement case-insensitive sorting:

The custom ItemDelegate "RegistryItemDelegate" will crash after mTreeView->setModel() take ProxyModel as argument instead of mModel.

How to make the QSortFilterProxyModel work with custom ItemDelegate? what code is missing?

```
RegistryTreeView::RegistryTreeView(Registry &inRegistry, QWidget *inParent)
{
    mModel = new RegistryItemModel;
    mModel->setRegistry(&inRegistry);

    QSortFilterProxyModel *ProxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    ProxyModel->setSourceModel(mModel);
    ProxyModel->setSortCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    ProxyModel->sort(0, Qt::DescendingOrder);

    mTreeView = new QTreeView;
    mTreeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::DefaultContextMenu);
    //mTreeView->setModel(mModel);
    mTreeView->setModel(ProxyModel);
    mTreeView->setItemDelegate(new RegistryItemDelegate(mModel));
    mTreeView->installEventFilter(new A utoSelectEventFilter(this));
    
    mainLayout->addWidget(mTreeView);
    
}

class RegistryItemModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
Q_OBJECT;

public:
RegistryItemModel(QWidget *parent=NULL);
virtual ~RegistryItemModel();
......
}
```

[image]

When using mTreeView->setModel(mModel):

[image]

When using mTreeView->setModel(ProxyModel):

[image]

```
void RegistryItemDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *inOption, const QModelIndex &inIndex) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(inOption, inIndex);

    const Node *node = mModel->node(inIndex);// the inIndex are different when using ProxyModel and mModel, and get a Node object which is not null, but will get a access violation exception when calling isDefault().  
    
    if(node == NULL)
        return;

    if(!node->isDefault())
        inOption->palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, mModifiedColor);

    if(node->nodeType() == eRegDir && inOption->version == 4)
    { 
        ((QStyleOptionViewItemV4*)inOption)->features |= QStyleOptionViewItemV2::HasDecoration;
        ((QStyleOptionViewItemV4*)inOption)->icon = mFolderIcon;
    }
}

 class Node
 {
    protected:
        Node(const QString &inName);


    private:
        Node(const QString &inName, Node *inParent);
        Node(const Node &inNode);


    public:
        virtual ~Node();
        virtual bool isDefault() const = 0;
  }

  class NodeKey : public Node
  class NodeDir : public Node
  bool NodeKey::isDefault() const
  {
      if(mDefaultValue.isNull())
          return false;

      if(mValue.isNull())
          return true;

      return mDefaultValue == mValue;
  }
  
  bool NodeDir::isDefault() const
  {
      foreach(Node *node, visibleChildren(false))
      {
         if(!node->isDefault())
         return false;
  }

       return mDefault;
  }
```

[image]
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
void RegistryItemDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *inOption, const QModelIndex &inIndex) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(inOption, inIndex);

    //const Node *node = mModel->node(inIndex);
    const Node* node = nullptr;

    QModelIndex sourceIndex = inIndex;
    auto proxyModel = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
    //We map the index back to its source as many times as needed.
    //We expect to do it once for now but that may change in the future.
    while (proxyModel) {
          sourceIndex = proxyModel->mapToSource(sourceIndex);
          proxyModel = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
    }
    if (auto regModel = dynamic_cast<const RegistryItemModel*>(sourceIndex.model()) ; regModel) // line 38
       node = regModel->node(sourceIndex); // line 39
    
    if(node == NULL)
        return;

    if(!node->isDefault())
        inOption->palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, mModifiedColor);

    if(node->nodeType() == eRegDir && inOption->version == 4)
    { 
        ((QStyleOptionViewItemV4*)inOption)->features |= QStyleOptionViewItemV2::HasDecoration;
        ((QStyleOptionViewItemV4*)inOption)->icon = mFolderIcon;
    }
}
```

Building errors:

ClCompile:
1>  RegistryItemDelegate.cpp
1>RegistryItemDelegate.cpp(38): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>RegistryItemDelegate.cpp(38): warning C4390: ';' : empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?
1>RegistryItemDelegate.cpp(38): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>RegistryItemDelegate.cpp(39): error C2065: 'regModel' : undeclared identifier
1>RegistryItemDelegate.cpp(39): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'node'
1>RegistryItemDelegate.cpp(39): error C2065: 'regModel' : undeclared identifier
1>RegistryItemDelegate.cpp(39): error C2227: left of '->node' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is ''unknown-type''

Comment: This error has nothing to do with model-delegate interaction; Please provide the code where you say the error occurs (not a screenshot) and additional debug information. Besides, it looks strange to me that you framed it this way and manually highlighted the line when you could have left the debugger's mark, as if that is not really where the error occurs; it could be *inside* the isDefault method. BTW, you are on C++ so `NULL` or C-style casting is to avoid (+ `QStyleOptionViewItemV4` has been obsolete for a while, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionviewitem-obsolete.html)).

Comment: @Atmo, thanks, is Default is a pure virtual function, when mTreeView->setModel using mModel, there is no crash.

Comment: I am a little bit curious; if it has pure virtual method, how do you get an instance? Or should I say: can you please provide the code of `RegistryItemModel::node` so we figure out how the compiler is not screaming at you for instantiating an abstract class? Regarding the comment you have added, that is a big clue indeed. But I am afraid without the answer to my previous question, I still do not have the full picture.

Comment: @Atmo There are NodeKey and NodeDir derived from Node and The Isdefault is implemented in these two classes. I attached a pic to show where this "QModelIndex inIndex" come from.
When I feed the proxymodel to mTreeView->setModel(), that "QModelIndex inIndex" is not the same, and mModel->node(inIndex) will not return a expected NodeKey or NodeDir.

Comment: In the future, please post code, not pictures. What would you do if nobody picked up your question? Anyway, I answered it.

Comment: @Atmo Thanks. I was told that another way I can implement case-insensitive sorting is to override the virtual QAbstractItemModel::sort() to implement your own case-insensitive sorting. Do you know where can I find some code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have guessed, the issue comes from `inIndex` being an index of your `QSortFilterProxyModel` rather than an index of your `RegistryItemModel`. Hopefully, `QAbstractProxyModel` (the base class for `QSortFilterProxyModel`) provides everything you need to map `inIndex` back to the source model.

I will assume you may have 0, 1 or several layers of proxy models, that is the model attached to your view is a chain that may ressemble: `QAbstractProxyModel`
-> `QAbstractProxyModel` -> `...` -> `RegisterItemModel`.
I am going to call **layers** the number of proxy models between what is attached to your view (included) and your instance of `RegisterItemModel`.

You can do:

```
const Node* node = nullptr;

QModelIndex sourceIndex = inIndex;
auto proxyModel = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
//We map the index back to its source as many times as needed.
//We expect to do it once for now but that may change in the future.
while (proxyModel) {
    sourceIndex = proxyModel->mapToSource(sourceIndex);
    proxyModel = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
}
if (auto regModel = dynamic_cast<const RegistryItemModel*>(sourceIndex.model()); regModel)
    node = regModel->node(sourceIndex);
```

---

**Edit:**
In Qt5 / C++14 or earlier the following `if`:

```
if (auto regModel = dynamic_cast<const RegistryItemModel*>(sourceIndex.model()); regModel)
    node = regModel->node(sourceIndex);
```

must be changed to 2 separate line of code:

```
auto regModel = dynamic_cast<const RegistryItemModel*>(sourceIndex.model()) ;
if (regModel)
    node = regModel->node(sourceIndex);
```

To be complete, it is also possible to use the return value of the assignment operator but I am not fond of this solution. It always look as if a `==` was mistakingly turned into a `=`:

```
if (auto regModel = dynamic_cast<const RegistryItemModel*>(sourceIndex.model()))
    node = regModel->node(sourceIndex);
```

Qt5 is reaching its end of life and not going to receive any further improvement. I strongly recommend you switch to Qt6 / C++17, the sooner the better.

---

I have not tested if the `dynamic_cast` is going to be the dominant contributor to the execution time but just in case, it can be optimized away by adding  2 attribute members to your delegate (`mutable unsigned int layerCount;` &  `mutable QAbstractItemModel* savedModel;`) and doing something like:

```
const Node* node = nullptr;

QModelIndex sourceIndex = inIndex;
const RegistryItemModel* regModel = nullptr;

//We test if the delegate knows the model used.
if (savedModel == inIndex.model()) {
    //We already did the mapping back to the source for inIndex.model()
    //We know how many layers of QAbstractProxyModel must be browsed through.
    for (unsigned int l = 0; l < layerCount; ++l) {
        auto proxyModel = static_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
        sourceIndex = proxyModel->mapToSource(sourceIndex);
    }
    regModel = static_cast<const RegistryItemModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
}
else {
    //We have not done the mapping back to the source yet.
    //We must discover how many layers of QAbstractProxyModel there are.
    auto proxyModel = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
    savedModel = const_cast<QAbstractItemModel*>(inIndex.model());
    layerCount = 0;
    //We map the index back to its source as many times as needed.
    //While we do so, we save how many layers there are so we can use the above faster loop next time.
    while (proxyModel) {
        ++layerCount;
        sourceIndex = proxyModel->mapToSource(sourceIndex);
        proxyModel = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
    }
    regModel = dynamic_cast<const RegistryItemModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
    if (!regModel)
        savedModel = nullptr;
}
if (regModel)
    node = regModel->node(sourceIndex);
[...]
```

Note that with  this optimization, you cannot change the number of layers to your model, except if you change the top one, meaning the layer you add/remove is the one attached to your view.

Comment: could you look at this new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170343/how-to-resolve-the-exception-qsortfilterproxymodel-index-from-wrong-model-pass  @Atmo