# How to resolve the exception: QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapToSource?

Tags: qt, qtreeview

Below is the code to run when clicking a "Next" button besides the QTreeview control and it will move the current selected tree node to the next sibling node. but clicking a "Next" button will trigger a exception, please advise how to resolve it?

```
void RegistryTreeView::findNext()
{
    QModelIndex fromIdx;

    QModelIndexList selectedIndexes = mTreeView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    if(selectedIndexes.isEmpty())
        fromIdx = mModel->index(0, 0); /* root */
    else
        fromIdx = selectedIndexes.first();
    
    QModelIndex nextIdx = findNext(mSearchEdit->text(), fromIdx);

    if(!nextIdx.isValid())
        return;

    mTreeView->expand(nextIdx);
    mTreeView->scrollTo(nextIdx);
    mTreeView->selectionModel()->clear();
    //exception throw out here.
    mTreeView->selectionModel()->select(nextIdx, QItemSelectionModel::Select); 
    //exception throw out here.
}

QModelIndex RegistryTreeView::findNext(const QString &inSearch, const QModelIndex &inFrom) const
{
    QModelIndex nextIdx;
    QModelIndex fromIdx = inFrom;

    while(true)
    {
        nextIdx = _findNext(inSearch, fromIdx, inFrom);
        if(nextIdx.isValid())
            return nextIdx;

        if(fromIdx.isValid())
        {
            do
            {
                if(fromIdx.sibling(fromIdx.row()+1, 0).isValid())
                {
                    fromIdx = fromIdx.sibling(fromIdx.row()+1, 0);
                    break;
                }

                fromIdx = fromIdx.parent(); 
            }
            while(fromIdx.isValid());
        }
        else
            break; /* was root */
    }

    return nextIdx;
}

QModelIndex RegistryTreeView::_findNext(const QString &inSearch, const QModelIndex &inParent, const QModelIndex &inExclude) const
{
    if(mModel->data(inParent, Qt::DisplayRole).toString().contains(inSearch, Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        if(inParent != inExclude)
            return inParent;
    }


    int nbChildren = mModel->rowCount(inParent);

    for(int i=0; i<nbChildren; i++)
    {
        QModelIndex childIdx = mModel->index(i, 0, inParent);

        QModelIndex nextIdx = _findNext(inSearch, childIdx, inExclude);
        if(nextIdx.isValid())
        {
            return nextIdx;
        }
    }

    return QModelIndex();
}

const Node* RegistryItemModel::nodeByProxyModelIndex(const QModelIndex &inIndex) const
{
    const Node* node = nullptr;

    QModelIndex sourceIndex = inIndex;
    auto proxyModel = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
    //We map the index back to its source as many times as needed.
    //We expect to do it once for now but that may change in the future.
    while (proxyModel) {
          sourceIndex = proxyModel->mapToSource(sourceIndex);
          proxyModel = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceIndex.model());
    }
   
    auto regModel = dynamic_cast<const RegistryItemModel*>(sourceIndex.model()) ;
    if (regModel)
    node = regModel->node(sourceIndex);
    return node;
}
```

[image]

Reference question:
[How to make QSortFilterProxyModel work with custom ItemDelegate of QTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945413/how-to-make-qsortfilterproxymodel-work-with-custom-itemdelegate-of-qtreeview?noredirect=1#comment133968795_75945413)

Comment: @Atmo Could you take a look?

Comment: The "`mapToSource`" that I see in your code is in `nodeByProxyModelIndex`. The rest looks unnecessary and should be removed, especially since it does not contain the line that calls `nodeByProxyModelIndex`, to make the question more clear. Also, I do not understand how / why you need to explore proxy models in a method of your source model class (which `nodeByProxyModelIndex` is). Surely, `RegistryItemModel` needs not be aware of the proxy model(s) it is a source of. Something must have gone terribly wrong in your design for it to be end like this.

Comment: in order to implement case-insensitive sort. I changed the qtreeview control to use a QSortFilterProxyModel object (mTreeView->setModel(ProxyModel)) and I replaced all the  "mModel->node(index)" calls with "mModel->nodeByProxyModelIndex(index)", this exception is a regression problem of my code change.

Comment: I have not understood your explanation. But it does not matter in fact, I can assure you without understanding what you're trying to achieve that you have to review your design from scratch. At worst, create a subclass of `QSortFilterProxyModel` to add a `node()` method to it (that will call its source model's node method) but calls should **NEVER** be the other way around.